# Integrating Velocity Over a Complex 2-D Surface

Tags: matlab, interpolation, triangulation, numerical-integration

I'm using matlab to calculate the the average velocity in the cross section of a pipe by integrating discrete velocity points over a surface. The points are scattered in a random pattern that form a circle (almost).

I used scatteredinterpolant to create a function relating x and y to v (velocity) in order to create a grid of interpolated values.

```
F = scatteredInterpolant(x, y, v,'linear');

vq = F(xq,yq); % where xq and yq are a set of query points
```

The problem I am now having is trying to calculate the the surface area of this function, but only in this circular portion that contains all the scatter points.

The first way I went about this was using the quad2d function.

```
int = quad2d(@(x,y) F(x,y), min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y), 'MaxFunEvals', 100000);
```

However this gives is incorrect as it takes the area over a rectangle and a circle.

Now I can probably define the surface area with a circle but in the future I will have to work with more complex shapes so I want to use points that define the boundary of the scatter points.

I'm doing this through triangulation, using the following command.

```
DT = delaunayTriangulation(x,y);
```

However I have no idea how I can incorporate these points into a quad2d function. I was hoping someone might have a suggestion or possibly another method I could use in calculating the area over these complex surfaces.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assume your function to be piecewise linear on your integration area and then integrate it using a midpoint quadrature rule:

For every triangle you compute the midpoint value as the mean of the nodal values and multiply by the triangle's area. You sum it all up to get your integral.

```
function int = integrate(T, values)
    meanOnTriangle = mean(values(T.ConnectivityList),2);
    int = sum(getElementAreas(T).*meanOnTriangle);        
end

function areas = getElementAreas(T)
    X = @(d) T.Points(T.ConnectivityList(:,d),:);
    d21 = X(2)-X(1);
    d31 = X(3)-X(1);
    areas = abs(1/2*(d21(:,1).*d31(:,2)-d21(:,2).*d31(:,1)));
end
```

As your goal is the average velocity, you want to compute the following quantity:

```
averageVelocity = integrate(DT,v)/sum(getElementAreas(DT));
```

Comment: I was wondering if I had a much more complicated shape such as a heart. Is it possible for triangulation to get the points around the perimeter where the indentation is occurring instead of skipping over it as it is doing currently Or do I need to use a more complicated method.

Comment: @user5006725: That's the problem of triangulating your domain. A delaunay-triangulation will always get you the convex hull (no indentations). You could try [alpha shapes](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28851-alpha-shapes) or manually define the boundary and use [constrained delaunay triangulations](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/delaunay-triangulation.html#bspqi8a-12).

Comment: I've created a MATLAB chat room for us to discuss things MATLAB related, or for discussions that span beyond the limitations of a single comment. Visit us when you have time! - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab